# How do I get the money after the heist?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want to know how to get the money after the heist. I don't seem to be getting 750,000 after the first heist. Do I need to do anything special to get the money? Or should I just redo the mission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get the money until Lester sells the jewels.   This takes a few hours and is an automatic process. ( you do not have to do anything )

Comment: Ok thank you:)(as you can tell, I am a first time player)

Comment: No problem!  Up-vote and check this is the answer when you can please! :)

Answer (score 0):

You must complete the whole Sanoro Desert area, so keep doing the Chinese/Chef/Trevor missions until you track down michael in Los Santos